# Безопасное хранение данных в Angular.js-приложении

Tags: node.js, angularjs, безопасность

Допустим есть web-приложение на Angular.js и back-end на Node.js. И есть пользователи в нескольких группах. Для каждой группы на клиенте должна показываться своя view’шка. Каким образом максимально безопасно можно хранить на клиенте данные о его состоянии (залогинен/нет) и принадлежности к группе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На клиенте невозможно безопасно хранить данные. Вы всегда должны получать данные о состоянии пользователя с сервера.

Comment: Возможно, я не достаточно корректно написал, имеется в виду - как минимизировать потенциальный вред от возможности использования данных хранимых на клиенте.

Comment: А в чем вы видите вред от использования этих данных? Вы же будете хранить только информацию о том авторизован ли пользователь и его собственную группу. В этой информации нет ничего опасного.